# Windows 2008 R2 Hyper V Performance

Tags: hyper-v, performance-monitoring, scvmm

We would like to monitor/view our performance on all Virtual machines running on our Windows 2008 R2 Hyper V Server. We need the ability to view common stats live on the server and also be able to view reports?

I know about performance monitor, but not sure if there was more like a "dashboard" view so we can view performance ongoing from our display monitor.

Do you have any suggestions? Would SCVMM do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using Server Manager and viewing the Hyper-V role from another 2008 box or a Win7 machine will give you an "at a glance" of how much CPU is being used, as well as the memory currently allocated to each VM.

SCVMM however, will only do VM management, and won't get you the other items you are looking for either. You may want to look into SCOM.

Answer (score 1):

SCVMM works but it is limited in what it does in a lot of ways and you have to look at many different locations.  If you have System Center Operation Manager that is ideal it can bring a great deal of information into one place.

Answer (score -2):

SCOM. System Center OPERATIONS (!) manager. SCVMM is vm management. It basiacly does not colelc grained data - it relies on SCOM to do so. It can integrate, but it assumes SCOM to be there.